# ADF - Using parameter from loop in a copy data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a loop that loops over URL's to fetch ODATA. Then, a copy flow is created for every path in the oDATA service. However, I need to be able to pass the URL into these tables as well.

How can I add the URL (@pipeline().parameters.ProjectUrl) to my sink when I am unable to import schemas because I'm working with parameters? Note that my query is a select, like so:

```
$select=Field1,Field2,Field3
```

I'd like to add my parameter here, so it gets added to the tables.

THanks!

Comment: So, to clarify, you are asking how to insert a parameter into your query?

Comment: @MartinJaffer-MSFT Correct

Answer (score 0):

By copy flow do you mean 'a mapping data flow, which is used just to copy' ?

If that is the case, go into the flow, and add a parameter.  Keep the type as string (not all of the flow parameter types have pipeline equivalents).  Go back to the pipeline, and look at the execute data flow activity.  The parameter will now be visible in the activity.  When you click on the 'value' field, you can choose between 'Pipeline expression' and 'Data flow expression'.  Choose 'Pipeline expression' and place the `@pipeline().parameters.ProjectUrl` here.